# How can I list the contents of an lrzip file without extracting from the Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line, compression

How can I list the contents of a lrzip file created via lrztar without extracting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lrztar is a wrapper around tar and lrzip, the file it produces is a lrzip'd tarball.  Knowing this we can view a listing of the files within the tarball via:

```
lrzcat file.tar.lrz | tar -tv
```

This will perform a streaming decompression of the lrz tarball and then use the tar command to print the contents.

Answer (score 0):

The lrzip program comes with lrzcat (which is just basically lrzip -d -o -). This dumps the contents of the .lrz file to the screen.

Comment: lzcat works only on .xz files, my files are .tar.lrz (created with lrztar)

Comment: Ok, then you could try lrztar -d -o - (notice that last -, it specifies STDOUT, namely the screen). I have not tested this myself though.

Comment: Using lrzcat with -f option I get the cat output of the compressed binary files, I just need a list of the compressed files. Is it possible?